# iOS 9 Notifications - why is my app name missing when I request permission?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I am implementing my first iOS9 app with notifications. The notifications service, through Parse, is running fine. However, when I request permission from a new user to send notifications, I get the screen below, and I don't know why the App is referred to as "Null".

[image]

Comment: may be you should change your question title. It is misleading.

Comment: This occurs on both the sim and a device.

Comment: did u set the app ID description ? / DId u register the app ID ?

Comment: This sounds like you haven't set the app's name- that's what you would normally see where "Null" is displayed.

Comment: I've edited the title - good idea,,thanks..

Comment: hmm. I see the app name when I request Location Services.

Comment: Try this: Select your target, then go to the "Packaging" section of the "Build Settings" tab, and set "Product Name" there

Comment: Thx. That is set correctly (just checked)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you see the app at the Settings and if so is the name correct there ? Anyway, it looks more like an iOS bug than misconfigured project (it shouldn't have passed installation w/o a proper Display Name), a trusty restart of the device might help.

Comment: Yep, it shows fine everywhere else - Settings is ok, all certs and profiles look ok. I will report it as a possible iOS bug if I don't get a working answer today or tomorrow.

Comment: ideas are welcome though ;)

Comment: So how about restarting the device (by the way, are using a single device or a couple, does it happens on every device you tried) ?

Comment: It happens on three devices and the simulator. I've restarted all, multiple times over the last couple of days,  for various reasons..

Comment: Alright then, be advised Apple will request a sample project to reproduce the issue and if you are in need of a steps to fix the problem creating a [TSI](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) request is the way to go: Apple engineers will analyze the problem and provide you feedback as opposed to having the bug open w/o updates for indefinite time, they will still ask for a sample project.

Comment: Thanks all.. I appreciate all the ideas. SO at its best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check **Bundle display name** in the info.plist file. 
I think **CFBundleDisplayName** may be blank in info.plist file.

So set it as **$(PRODUCT_NAME)**.

[image]